# Error with pub_version_plus in patch commands on flutter package

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am using the [pub_version_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/pub_version_plus) package, I have installed it as
`flutter pub add --dev pub_version_plus`. Package version 1.0.2 has been installed.

When I try to increase the patch version, I expect the build versions to be reset, however it doesn't happen, I don't know if I'm missing something or I have to reset it manually.

I show an example:

```
$ flutter pub run pub_version_plus:main patch
[station_screen] "1.1.5" => "1.1.6"
$ flutter pub run pub_version_plus:main patch
[station_screen] "1.1.6" => "1.1.7"
$ flutter pub run pub_version_plus:main build
[station_screen] "1.1.7" => "1.1.7+1"
$ flutter pub run pub_version_plus:main build
[station_screen] "1.1.7+1" => "1.1.7+2"
$ flutter pub run pub_version_plus:main patch
[station_screen] "1.1.7+2" => "1.1.8+2"
```

I want version `1.1.7+2` to go to `1.1.8`

Answer (score 0):

patch #

Increments the patch version number - 0.0.X

```
test_package upgraded from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1

#! with build number
test_package upgraded from 1.0.0+4 to 1.0.1+0
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your answer, but I don't understand you. Have you posted a snippet of the documentation or a command? Would you tell me exactly the command I have to type to increment the patch version and reset the build version. Thanks